# Replace NAs with their respective column means from very large text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a large text file: 400k rows and 10k columns, all numeric data values as 0,1,2. File size ranging 5-10GBs. I have a few missing values: NAs in the file. I want to replace the NA values with the column means, i.e. NA value in column 'x' must be replaced by the mean value of column 'x'. These are the steps that I want to do :

1. Compute means of each column of my text file (excluding the header and starting from column7th)
2. Replace NA in each column with their respective column means
3. Write the modified file back as a txt file

**Data subset**:

```
IID  FID  PAT MAT SEX PHENOTYPE X1 X2 X3 X4......
1234 1234  0  0    1   -9       0  NA  0  1 
2346 2346  0  0    2   -9       1  2  NA  1
1334 1334  0  0    2   -9       2  NA  0  2
4566 4566  0  0    2   -9       2  2  NA  0
4567 4567  0  0    1   -9       NA NA  1  1

# total 400k rows and 10k columns
```

**Desired Output**:

```
# Assuming only 5 rows as given in the above example.
# Mean of column X1 = (0 + 1+ 2+ 2)/4 = 1.25
# Mean of column X2 =  (2 + 2)/2 = 2
# Mean of column X3 = (0 + 0 + 1)/3 = 0.33
# Mean of column X4 = No NAs, so no replacements

# Replacing NAs with respective means:

IID  FID  PAT MAT SEX PHENOTYPE X1   X2  X3   X4......
1234 1234  0  0    1   -9       0    2   0     1 
2346 2346  0  0    2   -9       1    2   0.33  1
1334 1334  0  0    2   -9       2    2   0     2
4566 4566  0  0    2   -9       2    2   0.33  0
4567 4567  0  0    1   -9       1.25 2   1     1
```

I tried this:

```
file="path/to/data.txt"

#get total number of columns
number_cols=$(awk -F' ' '{print NF; exit}' $file)

for ((i=7; i<=$number_cols; i=i+1))
do 
    echo $i
    # getting the mean of each column
    mean+=$(awk '{ total += $i } END { print total/NR }' $file)
done

# array of column means
echo ${mean[@]}

# find and replace (newstr must be replaced by respective column means)
find $file -type f -exec sed -i 's/NA/newstr/g' {} \;
```

However, this code is incomplete. The for loop is very slow since my data is huge. Is there another way to do this faster? I did this in Python and R, but it is too slow. I am open to get this done in any programming language as long as it is fast. Can someone please help me write the script?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Added the desired output, thanks

Comment: I would recommend to use a file format that is designed for huge files, like [HDF5](https://www.h5py.org/). This would definitely help you to get and set the right values to the right places.

Comment: (1) First, your approach reads the entire data #column times, which is
very inefficient. Columnwise operation requires frequent seek across rows
anyway. Try to transpose the data in advance so you can access
all entries of the specified column as a line. Then you can store the column
data in a memory all at once to access them swiftly.
(2) Do not use bash, awk or other scripting language. Their indexing mechanism
of array is not efficient in terms of access time. I'd adopt C or C++
which stores each element of array in a linear address, enabling the
addressing of the element very fast.

Comment: (3) Please reconsider the purpose and the requirement. Interpolating the
NA value with other values means you are creating untrue data anyway.
I don't think you need to use whole column data for the purpose.
I'd just use the value in the previos line or a few lines around.
It might be better to discard the row which contains NA value
as a *data cleansing* depending on the purpose.
The decision may require statistics background and engineering sense of
compromisation.

Comment: @tshiono Thanks for your suggestion. However, I do not want to remove the entire row/column to eliminate NAs as that leads to a lot of loss of information and affects my downstream analysis. I have a very limited experience with C/C++, could you help me write the script to perform the above operations ? 
Thanks

Comment: Then I'd agree with the recommendation by @MaxPowers if you have an experience with python. Otherwise I will propose a Plan B option then.